# How to get last node created in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

So I know when you created nodes neo4j has a UUID for each node.  I know you can access a particular node by that UUID by accessing the ID.  For example:

`START n=node(144)
RETURN n;`

How would I get the last node that was created?  I know I could show all nodes and then run the same command in anotehr query with the corresponding ID, but is there a way to do this quickly?  Can I order nodes by id and limit by 1?  Is there a simpler way?  Either way I have not figured out how to do so through a simple cypher query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time not guaranteed that a new node always has a larger id than all previously created nodes,

So Better way is to set created_at property which stores current time-stamp while creating node.
You can use timestamp() function to store current time stamp

Then,

```
Match (n)
Return n
Order by n.created_at desc
Limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that Neo4j's internal node id is not a UUID. Nor is it guaranteed that a new node always has a larger id than all previously created nodes. The node id is (multiplied with some constant) the offset of the node's location within a store file. Due to space reclaiming a new node might get a lower id number.

**BIG FAT WARNING:** Do not take any assumption on node ids.

Depending on your requirements you could organize all nodes into a linked list. There is one "magic" node having a specific label, e.g. `References` that has always a relationship to the latest created node:

```
CREATE (entryPoint:Reference {to:'latest'}) // create reference node
```

When a node from your domain is created, you need to take multiple actions:

1. remove the `latest` relationships if existing
2. create your node
3. connect your new node to the previously latest node
4. create the reference link

.

```
MATCH (entryPoint:Reference {to:'latest'})-[r:latest]->(latestNode)
CREATE (domainNode:Person {name:'Foo'}),   // create your domain node
(domainNode)-[:previous]->(latestNode),    // build up a linked list based on creation timepoint
(entryPoint)-[:latest]->(domainNode)  // connect to reference node
DELETE r   //delete old reference link
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.  The ID() function will return the neo4j ID for a node:

`Match (n)
Return n
Order by ID(n) desc
Limit 1;`